# EntityFramework Database First Entity with custom constructors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've experience with Entity Framework with Code First approach, but now I need to work with Database First approach for the first time.
I got such entity:

```
[Table("Users")]    
public class User {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserTypeId")]
        public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
    }
```

I wanted to add custom constructors to this entity, so I added something like this:

```
public User() { }
public User(string username) => Login = username;
```

After adding constructors (the ones above are only examples) I got an error that my code does not reflect the database structure.
I cannot update this database structure, but having custom constructors in entities will make my code much simpler and comprehensive. Is there any option to add custom constructors or methods to this entities without need to update database structure?

**EDIT:** 
Exact error is: 
`System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).`

I'm sure there are no other changes to my entities than adding the constructors.

Comment: Please mention the exact error you are getting

Comment: @ReyanChougle I've edited my question and added exact error message.

Comment: [Entity types with constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors). Quote: _if EF Core finds a parameterized constructor with parameter names and types that match those of mapped properties_. So change `username` to `login`.

Comment: @Aenye_Cerbin, I think you are using EF6, not Core, because the error and the link above are referring to it. EF Core has not these problems if you are using Database First approach.

Comment: @FabioCaruso I've checked and you are right. Edited my quote.

Comment: Still, as long as there are parameterless constructors for each entity type, EF should be happy and not consider this a database change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using database-first, EF should be set up not to even inspect the schema. With EF Core migrations etc. are kicked off explicitly, but in EF6 they are enabled by default.

In your DbContext constructor, check for the following to disable the schema comparison and migrations: (Where "YourDbContext" = your DbContext class name)

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
```

As for multiple constructors, this is be perfectly fine. I commonly use parameterized public constructors with a protected default constructor to keep EF happy.